# Mysql Group ''close'' float ( lat / long )

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Background /**

Currently right now we have a 100 or so Lat/Lng wich get mapped onto google maps.  The aim is to show the hot spot location of these by selecting from the database La/Lo values that are within a few meters of each other.

The group values will then be used to find the central point and draw a circle on the map of the hot spot.

**Current setup /**

Currently the datase we are requesting from has just id(int),La(float),Lo(float)

**Concept /**

What i ''think'' is needed is this

```
Select * from table
Group by ( 
          ( La + 0.30 && La - 0.30) &&  ( Lo + 0.30 && Lo - 0.30) 
         )
```

Comment: What syntax is that? It looks like a cross between C# and SQL i.e. gibberish.

Comment: It was just pseudo,  concept code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the earth is not a square so to get accurate distances you will need to use a haversine function (look it up), however, for distances of a few metres , maybe accuracy doesn't matter.

Second, the distance between degrees of lattitude varies between 110.574 and 111.694 km and for degrees of longitude between 111.32 and 0.0 km (yes 0.0km at the poles). In any case 0.3 is somewhere between 0 and 35,000 m - not exactly "a few" unless your hotspots are at the north and/or south poles.

Third, ignoring the bad geography, the SQL statement you are groping for will require a cross join and sorting on calculated distances and will be very slow even for a small data set - you need to look at using whatever support mysql has for native geography types. I know SQL Server has them and I suspect MySQL does too.

**Edit**

It does, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296824/php-mysql-compare-long-and-lat-return-ones-under-10-miles?rq=1) question.